# Animate text after delay, sequential animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to animate text to match with some voice tracks, so each animation is on a delay.

I placed the times for the delays into data-audio, but have difficulty with .animate(), when trying to make them show sequentially.  I need them to show & begin animation, only after the delay has expired.

```
    function scaleText() {
    var t = $('.scalebox').data('times');
    if (t) {
        var anima = $('.scale');
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                 anima.eq(i).delay(t[i]).show().animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    fontSize: "4em"
                    }, 0, function() {
                        $( ".scale" ).animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        fontSize: "1.313em"
                        }, 4000);
                    });


            }
    }
}
```

If I don't put show(), then everything is invisible.  I can't figure out where to put show so that it will happen after delay.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/qPv8m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show()` is not an animated method, so it doesn't work with `delay()` as it's not added to the `FX` queue.
You can however make it an animated method by adding a duration

```
.show(1)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qPv8m/2/)

Comment: I was never going to get that answer on my own, thanks so much.